# How to introduce Artifical Humans into American society without causing the end of the world. How to do it?

Tags: society, robots

In my setting a team of scientists have created humanoid robots that mimic Human anatomy near-perfectly. The robots are sentient and can be replicated easily.

So my question is... How could the team of scientists introduce these robots to society without a World War breaking out?

Here's a list of how the robots body's are structured:

1. the robots have rubber for "skin"
2. The robots have a digestive system that is identical to ours... except the fact that it's synthetic (the scientists thought the the robots should be able to consume "food" in order to power themselves if they cannot locate an alternative power source).
3. The robots (if they eat) have a system that expells bodily wastes (similar to a human's)
4. The robots can consume water to cool themselves down (if needed)
5. The robots "skeletons" are composed of a synthetic calcium-like compound that mimics an organic skeleton.
6. The robots have NO respiratory system (they don't need to breathe)
7. The robots have a nervous system that is IDENTICAL to ours (except the fact that it's composed of synthetic materials).

To restate my question: How do I introduce these robots to the world WITHOUT starting WWIII

Comment: their make up is not as important as 1' how many they are, 2' how they behave,and 3' how they are made for understanding how they interact with society.

Comment: Why do you think a war would start? The usual trope is "robots are mistreated, then rise in revolt" Avoid it by not mistreating the robots.

Comment: If they can extract energy from food then they need to be able to breath. Energy is extracted from food by

Comment: *through combustion reactions, which require oxygen. Yo robots need to breath, man!

Answer (score 4):

**Make them more different.**

There's a funny effect in human psychology called the [Uncanny Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_valley).  As things become more and more human like, there is a sudden shift where we start to find that thing utterly repulsive before it gets human-like enough for us to appreciate it

[image: The Uncanny Valley]

Between the rubber skin and the lack of a respiratory system forcing them to have a very alien way of speaking (mechanical speakers?), I would expect your robots to fit square into the valley.

Better to make them look less lifelike first.  Then you can introduce them as subordinate to humans.  (I assume you intend them to be subordinate to humans.  An entity which is "replicated easily" which is on-par with humans is a very different topic entirely because it makes humanity easily replaceable)

Answer (score 0):

Introduce them as servant beings, then after everyone gets used to them, have a few notable ones achieve freedom, and then eventually encourage everyone to free their robot servants. Encourage people to give them paying jobs, and to serve them as regular customers, especially for shelter and energy needs (food/electrical/etc.).

As a sidenote, **Overwatch** is an interesting franchise for this question, because they're currently going through a similar thing in that world.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get someone who is disliked by the mainstream culture to publicly come out against.  Tie robot opposition to their other unpopular views.  Percolate this throughout society so that "everyone" knows that opposition to robots is backwards and bigoted.
2. Roll out the 'bots.